How can I deal with a question that answers itself?
The question is React State Not Updating correctly and is actually linking code that updates the state correctly. There's nothing to answer here, because there isn't any problem. Is this supposed to be flagged?


They didn't include a mcve in the question itself, or ask a specific technical question, so there's no action to be taken here even if the StackBlitz link didn't work.

Not sure why this is getting close votes for "can no longer be reproduced." Is the problem OP is asking about somehow not possible now?

This is one reason why links to code aren't acceptable.  If a change is made there's no way to see the history.

Posts like these make me want to suggest a "no issue here, just a misunderstanding what the code is doing" VTC reason. I'd close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". If OP pushes back and swears there's a problem, then ask them to provide better details and produce a complete [mcve], then hit them with the "needs debugging details" close reason if they can't provide anything.

Just generally, if there are questions that truly answer themselves (in the question body): one could simply cut out the answer from the question and put it into an answer (giving attribution).

@Cuzy Sure, if it is already closed. Oftentimes you may want to prompt the OP to edit their post first if you suspect there's a chance to salvage before casting votes to close.

This has been answered in this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429767/how-can-i-deal-with-a-question-that-answers-itself

@JK. What do you mean? That's just a link to this question itself.

Maybe he recently learned about recursion XD

Several closure reasons seem to apply:

"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo",
"Needs debugging details",
"Needs details or clarity"

However, these are only available once you pass 3000 reputation.
Until then, you can flag for these reasons, rather than vote to close.

@Cuzy close votes are locked behind that reputation cutoff. Flags aren't.

They're similar, but not quite the same :-)

@Cuzy Even if you don't have the rep to cast close votes, you can raise the corresponding flag under "needs improvement" and then I believe the question will end up in the "close vote review queue".

If the code the OP shows does not, in fact, have the problem they claim it does, it should be closed as "Not reproducible or caused by a typo". (If they have code that actually reproduces the problem or other instructions that allow us to actually reproduce their problem, they can edit the question with that so that it can be considered for reopening).
